# Query for Transactions per second?

Tags: mysql

For performance mornitoring, i would like to have a mysql query which gives the calculated output of TPS. I think tps= Com_commit + Com_rollback / second , but I don't know the query to calculate these formula in mysql. Same related question for TPS had been asked but query was not provided there, so why I ask here. Kindly show me how to calculate values from status in MySQL/MariaDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit clunky, but this should give you the tps since restart of MySQL:

```
SELECT  SUM(IF(variable_name IN ('Com_commit', 'Com_rollback'),
                   variable_value, 0)) /
        SUM(IF(variable_name = 'Uptime',
                   variable_value, 0))
    FROM  information_schema.GLOBAL_STATUS
```

Answer (score 0):

`Com_commit` and `Com_rollback` are available in `information_schema.global_status`.  You need to query them regularly and calculate the difference between readings in order to get `quantity per duration`.

When I tried to do something similar, a co-worker asked what it would really tell us.  His argument was that it told us nothing about transaction size - no way to know how much `work` was being done.  For example `BEGIN; COMMIT;` is a transaction, which will increase your counter, but not tell you anything. Also, if your `TPS` drops, is that because of a bottleneck, or a drop in application demand?

Don't let that stop you from implementing this monitoring, but make sure you know what you're getting from the number.

Comment: Thats ok ; but I was asking about the mysql Query for getting that value calculated from mysql prompt itself using some SUM() and ROUND functions in mysql. Could u be able to provide that ?